# Typescript: simulating nested classes + private member access

Tags: typescript, nested

Past answers posted regarding typescript and nested classes have suggested use of the declaration merging capability of the language.   I've tried this with the example below, which executes as intended, but generates a compiler message:

```
foo.ts(9,37): error TS2341: Property '_bar' is private and only accessible
              within class 'Foo'.
```

... which seems odd because as written, Class Bletch *is* a member of Foo.

**Is there a *best practice* way to suppress the error about accessing a private member of the outer class?**   (I know I can replace `this._foo` with `(this._foo as any)`, but it seems like there should be a more more elegant way...)

Example:

```
export class Foo {
    constructor( private _bar: number ){}
    //...
}

export module Foo {
    export class Bletch {
        constructor( private _foo: Foo ) {}
        barf(): number { return this._foo._bar; }
    }
}

let a = new Foo(57);
let b = new Foo.Bletch(a)

console.log(b.barf());
```

Answer (score 1):

Being a member of a class doesn't let you access its private members/methods, but usually inner classes can.
In this case though you don't really have an inner class, you just add the class `Bletch` as a property of class `Foo`, it's easier to see in the compiled js:

```
var Foo = (function () {
    function Foo(_bar) {
        this._bar = _bar;
    }
    return Foo;
}());
var Foo;
(function (Foo) {
    var Bletch = (function () {
        function Bletch(_foo) {
            this._foo = _foo;
        }
        Bletch.prototype.barf = function () { return this._foo._bar; };
        return Bletch;
    }());
    Foo.Bletch = Bletch;
})(Foo || (Foo = {}));
```

You can solve this by doing something like this:

```
module Foo {
    interface Instance {
        _bar: number;
    }

    export class Bletch {
        private _foo: Instance;

        constructor( foo: Instance | Foo ) {
            this._foo = foo as Instance;
        }

        barf(): number { return this._foo._bar; }
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Foo%20%7B%0A%09constructor(private%20_bar%3A%20number)%20%7B%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Amodule%20Foo%20%7B%0A%09interface%20Instance%20%7B%0A%09%09_bar%3A%20number%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%09%0A%09export%20class%20Bletch%20%7B%0A%09%09private%20_foo%3A%20Instance%3B%0A%09%09%0A%09%09constructor(%20private%20foo%3A%20Instance%20%7C%20Foo%20)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09this._foo%20%3D%20foo%20as%20Instance%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%0A%09%09barf()%3A%20number%20%7B%20return%20this._foo._bar%3B%20%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20new%20Foo(57)%3B%0Alet%20b%20%3D%20new%20Foo.Bletch(a)%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(b.barf())%3B))

You also have another way of defining "inner classes":

```
interface Instance {
    _bar: number;
}

class Foo {
    constructor( private _bar: number ) {}

    static Bletch = class {
        private _foo: Instance;

        constructor( foo: Instance | Foo ) {
            this._foo = foo as Instance;
        }

        barf(): number { return this._foo._bar; }
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Instance%20%7B%0A%09_bar%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Foo%20%7B%0A%09constructor(%20private%20_bar%3A%20number%20)%20%7B%7D%0A%09%0A%09static%20Bletch%20%3D%20class%20%7B%0A%09%09private%20_foo%3A%20Instance%3B%0A%09%09%0A%09%09constructor(%20private%20foo%3A%20Instance%20%7C%20Foo%20)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09this._foo%20%3D%20foo%20as%20Instance%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%0A%09%09barf()%3A%20number%20%7B%20return%20this._foo._bar%3B%20%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%7D))

Which looks more like how it's usually done, and it's a bit shorter.

Comment: OK, so defining an interface with the friend-accessable members, right?

Comment: I like your last example, though the syntax of declaring the class Bletch seems a bit forced.   Tthe only drawback I've detected is that Bletch seems to get labeled an "anonymous class" by VS Code IntelliSense.

Comment: P.S.  I proposed a minor tweak to your example code, gets rid of an extra private property.

Comment: Discovered one other disadvantage of the interface approach:  if the member names declared in class `Foo` and interface `Instance` differ, no compile-time error is generated.   A partial loss of type safety...

Comment: Yeah, because you want to have the member of `Foo` to be private then you can't implement the `Instance` interface and thus maintain the type safety.

Comment: I guess the distinction you made between a nested class and an inner class is Java specific; a bit foreign to me. .   In C++11, a nested class has full access to all members of the enclosing class, which is what I was hoping typescript would implement.

Comment: In Java you can also get access to private/protected members of the enclosing class. But as I wrote, typescript doesn't support inner classes and all of these solutions are workarounds.